# What does a universe look like where light cannot lose energy and is emitted all the time?

Tags: cosmology, electromagnetic-radiation, energy-conservation, universe

In a universe where light cannot lose energy, and is emitted all the time, what is the result?

Comment: Can you be more specific about this? In broad terms this describes our actual Universe pretty well.

Comment: That is a matter of opinion. I think tired light explains cosmological red shift. People who are in favour of universe expansion theory tend to dismiss it with no mechanism for light losing energy. Seems to me to contradict observed universe, based on what a universe would look like where light cannot lose energy and is emitted all the time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tired_light

Comment: Note, I am not in any way saying that the *data* is a matter of opinion. To avoid misunderstanding, I am saying that the theory to explain the data is a matter of opinion. In my opinion, that is a fundamental tenet of the scientific method, competing theories. I know others disagree, but, that is my stance on that.

Comment: The mechanism of light losing energy is the standing waves pushing on the "edges" of the universe

Answer (score 1):

Well if light could not lose energy and was emitted all the time, that would mean that the light could only remain at the same frequency or blueshift upwards. The total sum of that energy, being positive, would most likely continue to have a gravitational effect on the universe, continuing to contract it inwards, until the universe collapsed into a singularity. A concept called a kugelblitz is very similar and you can learn more about them by reading the original paper on them here:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.2778